# Error while extracting latest date with sapply

Tags: r

i have a dataframe with 6 date columns and i want to see latest date on each date columns.

i tried like this.

```
dateCols <- c("DATE1", "DATE2", "DATE3", "DATE4", "DATE5", "DATE6")
sapply(mydata[colnames(mydata) %in% dateCols], max, na.rm=T)
```

but it returns values of integer not Date.
For example, latest date of DATE1 column is `2016-06-30` but it returns `16982`.

`max(mydata$DATE1)` returns `2016-06-30` but `sapply` doesn't give me right value.
Why and how can i fix it?

Comment: @akrun Voting is anonymous, but have fun. I'm not here for the rep. But perhaps see [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/).

Comment: @Axeman I know voting is anonymous but dupe tagging not an exact solution and then downvoting a legitimate solution is also abusing power